# Created Custom Field doesnt update after clicking Save Changes on Woocommerce -> Settings -> Products tab page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I created a custom field for another input text under Woocommerce -> Settings -> Products tab page. But if doesnt save or update the value of the input text to database. Please can someone check if this code isnt right?

Note: This is tested and worked on single product pages, but seems that it doesnt work on woo settings.

```
/* Display Gravity Form ID custom field on Woocommerce -> Settings -> Products tab on backend */
add_action('woocommerce_settings_products', 'enquiry_button_product_pages');
function enquiry_button_product_pages() {
  global $woocommerce, $post;
  $gf_id_field = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_gf_field', true );
  echo "<h2>Single Product Pages</h2>";
  echo '<p>Enter the Gravity form ID of the enquiry form you will be using here.</p>';?>
  <table class="form-table">
    <tbody>
      <tr class="single_select_page" valign="top">
        <th scope="row" class="titledesc">
          <label>Gravity Form ID number:</label>
        </th>
        <td class="forminp">
          <?php
            woocommerce_wp_text_input(
                array(
                    'id' => '_gf_field',
                    'value' => $gf_id_field,
                    'desc_tip' => 'false',
                    'priority'  => 1,
                    'type'      => 'number'
                )
            );
          ?>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
<?php
}


/* Save custom fields to access via get_post_meta */
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'custom_gf_id_save' );
function custom_gf_id_save ($post_id) {

    $woo_gf_id_field = $_POST['_gf_field'];
    
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_gf_field', esc_attr( $woo_gf_id_field ) );

}
```

Thank you

Comment: You're using the wrong hook to save, also the hook for adding the field can be modified to save automatically. Do you intend to add a new field to the WooCommerce -> Settings -> Products -> General tab? Or is it a different tab? may the field be added at the bottom of the existing fields, or is it the intention to display it between certain existing fields?

Comment: That is intended for woo -> settings -> products -> General tab at the top of all existing fields.. Actually the new field is already in the place, its just that it is not saving when clicking "Save Changes" button.